# How to get the name of the exe in the Innosetup script from the full path of the exe is given?

Tags: installation, inno-setup, uninstallation

For example if the full file path of the exe is provided as `C:\Projects\Executable\Serial Data Streaming Recorder.exe`, I need to extract the name of the exe. That is `Serial Data Streaming Recorder` and I want to dynamically assign this value to a variable from the full file path of exe.

Manually done like in below example:

```
#define ExePath "C:\Projects\Executable\Serial Data Streaming Recorder.exe"
#define AppName "Serial Data Streaming Recorder"
```

I want to dynamically assign the value `Serial Data Streaming Recorder` to the variable `AppName` from the full file path of exe.

I'm using this name in many places in the inno script for many files, So i don't want to do it manually by assigning this value to a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm... I usually solve this simply by never using any absolute paths in my install scripts. You can also just define ExePath like this:

```
#define BasicName "Serial Data Streaming Recorder"
#define ExePath   "C:\Projects\Executable\" + BasicName + ".exe"
```

and then use `{#BasicName}` whenever you need just the name.

There are also several preprocessor script functions (not pascalscript) that can do string manipulations to do more advanced stuff.

Comment: #define MyExePath    "C:\Executable\Serial Data Streaming Recorder.exe" <br />
#define MyAppExeName ExtractFileName (MyExePath)
#define MyAppName    Copy(MyAppExeName, 1, Pos(".exe", MyAppExeName) - 1)

I solve it like this........:)

Answer (score 3):

To do this at runtime in `[Code]` You can get the file name and extension using the [`ExtractFileName()`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_extractfilename.htm). I think you can then remove the extension by passing blank to the [`ChangeFileExt()`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_changefileext.htm) function but if not, you can find and remove it using standard string operations like [`Pos()`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_pos.htm) and [`Delete()`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_delete.htm).

If you need to do this at compile time, you need to use ISPP, most of the functions have the same name and signature so use `ExtractFileName()` to get the file name itself, `RPos()` to get the period and `Delete()` to remove it.

Comment: Thanks for you for your reply.I cannot change delete file extension using ChangeFileExt() it returns "." at the end of the name.
Possible provide me some ways to delete last 4 characters, Still i gave kudos.

Comment: I did, use `RPos()` and `Delete()` in ISPP.